# Dart adaj error

Tags: ajax, http-post, dart

I am trying to use Dart's [adaj](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/adaj) library:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:convert';
import "package:adaj/adaj.dart" as http;

void main() {
    Map data = {
        "email": "john.smith@example.com",
        "password": "12345"
    };

    var url = "http://localhost:8080/myapp/signin";

    http.post(url, data).fail(onFail).always(alwaysHandler).done(onSuccess).go();
}

void onFail(String failMsg) {
    window.alert("Error! " + failMsg);
}

void alwaysHandler(dynamic response) {
    window.alert("Always executing");
}

void onSuccess(Map json) {
    window.alert("The returned json is : " + json['answer']);

    if(json == 1)
        window.alert("You are signed in!");
    else
        window.alert("Sign in failed. Check credentials.");
}
```

When I run this code, I expect to get a value of "1" back from the server, which should then result with an alert box being rendered with the text "You are signed in!" in it.

Instead, when I run this code, I get an alert that say "*Error! 1*", and then a 2nd alert that says "*Always executing: 1*".

Any ideas as to where the error is coming from? When I run this in Firebug I see the HTTP POST response from the server is "1", which means its definitely a client-side bug.

Comment: What is the response status? 200 OK?

Comment: Thanks @PixelElephant (+1) - response is 200 OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because adaj attempts to treat the response as a map. You can see this in the [source](https://github.com/daydev/adaj/blob/master/lib/adaj.dart):

```
Map result = request.responseText.isEmpty ? {} : JSON.decode(request.responseText);
```

Since `1` cannot be coerced into a Map, an error is thrown.

You can solve this by returning something like `{ "code": 1 }` instead, which can be properly converted to a Map.

You will also have to change the onSuccess callback param to Map type, and change alwaysHandler param type to dynamic, since the always callback will be called with a Map if the post was successful and with a String if there was an error.

Below is the final code you should have:

```
import 'dart:html';
import "package:adaj/adaj.dart" as http;

void main() {
    Map data = {
        "email": "john.smith@example.com",
        "password": "12345"
    };

    var url = "http://localhost:8080/myapp/signin";

    http.post(url, data).fail(onFail).always(alwaysHandler).done(onSuccess).go();
}

void onFail(String failMsg) {
    window.alert("Error! " + failMsg);
}

void alwaysHandler(dynamic response) {
    window.alert("Always executing");
}

void onSuccess(Map json) {
    window.alert("The returned json is :  ${json['answer']}");

    if(json['answer'] == 1)
        window.alert("You are signed in!");
    else
        window.alert("Sign in failed. Check credentials.");
}
```

With this code I receive the following alerts:

```
"Always executing"
"The returned json is: 1"
"You are signed in!"
```

Comment: Thanks again @PixelElephant (+1) - I modified the server to respond with "`{ "answer": 1 }`" instead of just "1", and am getting "Illegal argument errors" in Firebug. **Can you perhaps post an example of how to use Adaj's `post` method, including `fail()`, `always()`, `done()` and `go()`?** I think seeing a working example would help enormously. Thanks again!

Comment: @TicketMonster I've added some extra info about changing the callbacks to accept the proper type. Otherwise it looks like you are using them fine.

Comment: Thanks again @PixelElephant (+1) - please see my code changes to reflect your suggestions. Now, when I run the code, the `alwaysHandler` fires, then the `onFail` handler fires, and then the `alwaysHandler` fires **a second time**...any ideas? Am I accessing the `answer` incorrectly in the json map somehow? Again the response from the server is HTTP 200 OK, and the JSON is `{ "answer": 1 }`.

Comment: @TicketMonster You made a few mistakes in onSuccess. Integers cannot be concatenated with Strings, convert it to a String first or use String interpolation. Also, you checked if `json == 1` but json is a Map, instead you must check if `json['answer'] == 1`. I've updated my answer with working code.